# Make a module that allows admins to upload file to web dir, from administration area?

Tags: magento2, upload, file, section

I am new to magento2, and I was put on a task to make a new section, or to somehow allow admins to upload a file from administration area, and save it to web folder, always under same name. File is in .csv format

Any ideas on how to do this? So far I've only done frontend in magento, and Im lost here. Tried googling, but solutions I found did not work.

Thank you for your help and patience.

Comment: Do you want it on admin forms or on system configuration?

Comment: If possible, under stores->configuration @SukumarGorai

Comment: Can you try this one https://inchoo.net/magento-2/file-upload-in-magento-2-store-configuration/

Comment: @SukumarGorai Hmm, I get this error: http://prntscr.com/jw7rek after I do setup:upgrade

Comment: Did you follow the paths correctly?

Comment: @SukumarGorai Hmm, think so? Here are my files, which are in : app/code/"vendor"/ http://prntscr.com/jw7vi2